# Using same SSL cert for 2 domains with same IP

Tags: ssl-certificate, symantec

We have a SSL cert from Symantec for foo.bar.com. Now we want our site to be know as foo.baz.com while still maintaining the old name. Both bar.com and baz.com resolve to the same IP. If I go to foo.baz.com it says the site is not secure. How I can use the same cert for both domain names when they are the same IP?

Comment: You can support multiple SSL/TLS servers on one IP (&port) using a single cert with SubjectAlternativeName (SAN, aka UCC) or multiple certs and ServerNameIndication (SNI) depending on your software and possibly client(s). This is not a programming question and will probably be closed here, but it is ontopic and dupe at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/807959) and [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/107377) For Symantec see https://www.websecurity.symantec.com/security-topics/san-ssl-certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already purchased SSL certificate for foo.ar.com but not for foo.baz.com that's why it says '**site is not secure**'.

[Symantec SSL certificates](https://www.clickssl.net/platinum-partner-of-symantec-ssl-certificates) are giving support for SAN (Subject Alternative Names) so you can manage multi domain names with single Symantec SSL certificate so add you domain name foo.baz.com in existing SSL certificate.